# rails_admin using separate login pages for admin and user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rails-admin

I'm using rails_admin and devise gem for my rails 5 project. I used CanCanCan for authorization. My problem is i must use separate login pages, one for normal user and one for admin user (now it uses same login page for both).
Does anyone has solution for my problem?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You find more info in the below link for multiple devise user model:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to-Setup-Multiple-Devise-User-Models

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use two different paths use `namespace` in your `routes.rb`

Example:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'user#index'
  .
  .
  .
  namespace :admin do

    root to: 'dashboard#index'
    .
    .
    .
  end

end
```

Don't forget that you will have to namespace all the controllers that you plan to include in the admin section, as well as remember to have those files on the proper folder.

For the above example you should have the admin controller inside the path `app/controllers/admin/dashboard_controller.rb` and the content of the controller should be similar to the below code

```
class Admin::DashboardController < ActionController::Base
  def index
  end
end
```

if you want to use one single login page for both admins and users, then you'll have to use a common controller to handle both